# How can I programmatically add a statement at the beginning of all function's body in a file?

Tags: go, trace

I want to add one line (something like printing funtion name, file name, line no.) at the beginning of all the function bodies in a file. This is to log the execution flow of some functionalities of a big project. There is zero or almost negligible logging in the entire project and I am trying to figure a way out.

Comment: so wait, this is not really go right? You want a way to add some text to into a document based on a predefined pattern, if I got it right

Comment: Actually, this about a golang project.

Comment: You can add text to the source files using any text processing tooling you'd like, but there's an example [here](https://github.com/jbardin/gotrace/) of doing this in Go.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the link. I will try that out. I was also thinking we should be able to tweak gofmt code, but not sure how easy that will be.

Comment: @JimB Thanks again. The tool perfectly fits the requirement.